# Android app against Coronavirus (COVID-19) Epidemic

Tags: web-apps, health

Due to the **corona virus epidemic** and the lack of effective methods for the treatment of this disease, I sense having one android app could be useful in many area like:

1. giving useful medical recommendation to its users.
2. locating the suspect of corona virus by volunteer activities to
   declare it via app and registering some their information, which
   could be useful in ???
3. going to test none verified cure or control methods which is
       declared via internet by volunteer activity to test it on
       themselves. ( it must be found its most effective and sorted by more
       near scientific ways, and have many human rights challenges which
       must be considered in making this method by tanking a look to
       similar laboratory test routines)

based of these needs i suggest use opensource team working method by creating one team to try finding a legal and practical way to inform, control and collect basic data to test new ways to alleviate or treat complications. This disease is caused.

Requirements for review:

1. Examine the ability of the group to be absorbed in the fields,
   programming and preparation of the application and site required
   Access to the information and communications needed in the field of
   technology and medical cases to design and review applicable
   mechanisms and optimally select up-site and site design methods.
2. Access to information and ethical and legal rules Implementation of
   such a plan domestically and in other countries according to
   existing needs and access to more data if larger geographical
   choices are made. Examine supportive mechanisms, such as
   governmental and non-governmental organizations, to engage these
   organizations to correct and influence each other and to establish
   effective communication based on the needs of both parties.
3. Others (suggested by others) question

I it could be legal here to create one external commutation group like GitHub page on telegram group or ... ,  which could be done and declared here for concentrating on working on it's codes and having volunteer efforts on this goal on it at that location.

Thanks

Comment: This are great ideas, and a very kind post.  Unfortunately, it's off-topic here.  Because of the unique urgency and critical nature of this issue, I'm electing to not close it at this time.  Others here may have good suggestions of more beneficial places to post your ideas.

Comment: As indicated, *This site is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task, that is, “what software can I use to do …?”* (see [help/on-topic] where this is quoted from). So if you're asking for such an app, please [edit] your post and adjust it accordingly. Further, as you even mention Github: have you seen [these 200+ projects](https://github.com/search?q=corona+virus)?